# Send My Location From android Phone to my email

Tags: android, python, vb.net, kivy

I am developing an application for my friend. I need to send my location coordinate to my mail or to any IP through a simple android app. I can code in VB.Net and Python, but I have no experience with android. I installed Kivy and I can make a "Hello Program" with it, but I am unable to think how to send my location.

Any method is acceptable. Even if there are external API's that can be used, I am okay with it. But I need something that works with Python or VB.net. I know that my question my be down-voted, but I need help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Python/Kivy can access android's java apis using pyjnius, including (as you require) the GPS.

The easiest way to do this is through [plyer](https://github.com/kivy/plyer), a nice set of libraries abstracting hardware access to try and run seamlessly on different systems. The important thing for you is that it includes everything you need to access the gps api, as per the included example that you can find [here](https://github.com/kivy/plyer/blob/master/examples/gps/main.py). Don't forget your apk will also need the right permissions, like in the example python-for-android build command in the [gps README](https://github.com/kivy/plyer/tree/master/examples/gps).

sl4a also has some gps tools, but I don't know the details of using them and I kivy doesn't currently have sl4a access (though there was some work on that very recently).

Comment: How will I install plyer on android? Till now, I have created a simple  hello script in python, and put the file in folder kivy on my sdcard, and named it main.py. But how will I use plyer on android. I have installed kivy launcher on android device.

Comment: Plyer is a python module, you need to include it with your program. I don't know if/how the kivy launcher handles this. I would instead build a proper standalone apk with the buildozer tool, with which it is easy to include plyer (and other python modules).